# In Keras how to get the `class_indices` or prediction labels for an existing model

Tags: keras, cnn, prediction

I know that keras provides a `.class_indicies` dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class as part of `.flow_from_directory()` from its `ImageDataGenerator` class  (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

HOWEVER, is there a way to access the corresponding class labels from an existing *saved* model (a model saved in as an .h5 file)?  This seems important when putting my model into production and serving predictions since the classes are not known upfront and therefore the images are not separated in pre-labeled directories.

Similarly, are there any good examples of how a keras model should be deployed into production (especially for mobile)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you solved already.
I faced this problem yesterday, and the only solution that came to my mind is saving a dictionary to a `numpy` file after a `train_generator` is set; something like:

```
np.save('FILENAME', self.train_generator.class_indices)
```

when you finish your training. 
Then, when you do your single prediction:

```
single_pred = np.squeeze(self.model.predict(image))

if isfile('FILENAME.npy'):
    class_indices = np.load(self.indices_file + '.npy').item()

results_dict = dict(zip(class_indices.keys(), single_pred))
```